# How to convert string literal to the value of the variable with the same name?

Tags: c++, macros

I'm running a function where I intake a string literal of a signal ie "SIGINT". However, I need to convert this to  the value of the macro SIGINT. Is this possible to do, without doing a series of if statements?

```
uint8_t sigNumber = 0;
 if(name =="SIGINT") {
   sigNumber = SIGINT;
 } else if (...)
```

Comment: Not possible. You can generate the `if`s with macros (or you can fill a `std::map` with them, or ...), but that's it.

Comment: That depends. If `name` is a `std::string`, `name =="SIGINT"` will be groovy. For this I would consider using a `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` to keep the code small/easily modified, but there aren't many official signals, so the cascade if `if`/`else if` will probably be the most performant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 using std:c++latest:

```
// #include <csignal>
#define SIGINT     2  // interrupt
#define SIGILL     4  // illegal instruction - invalid function image
#define SIGFPE     8  // floating point exception
#define SIGSEGV   11  // segment violation
#define SIGTERM   15  // Software termination signal from kill
#define SIGBREAK  21  // Ctrl-Break sequence
#define SIGABRT   22  // abnormal termination triggered by abort call

constexpr
std::pair<int, std::string_view>  sig_mapping [] {
    {SIGINT,   "SIGINT"},
    {SIGILL,   "SIGILL"},
    {SIGFPE,   "SIGFPE"},
    {SIGSEGV,  "SIGSEGV"},
    {SIGTERM,  "SIGTERM"},
    {SIGBREAK, "SIGBREAK"},
    {SIGABRT,  "SIGABRT"},
};

template<int SIZE>
constexpr
int StringToValue( const char (&STR) [SIZE] )
{
    for( auto &&i : sig_mapping ) {
        if( i.second == STR )  return i.first;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto
        sigunknown { StringToValue("UNKNOWN") },
        sigint     { StringToValue("SIGINT") },
        sigill     { StringToValue("SIGILL") },
        sigfpe     { StringToValue("SIGFPE") },
        sigsegv    { StringToValue("SIGSEGV") },
        sigterm    { StringToValue("SIGTERM") },
        sigbreak   { StringToValue("SIGBREAK") },
        sigabort   { StringToValue("SIGABRT") }
    ;
    return 0;
}
```